# regex for JSON only for one nested data

Tags: python, regex

Hi guys do you know how to change [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/6PUWN9/1), that it only looks for test :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply two regexes: first, get `r'^test:.*$'` with `m` option, then your original regex on the result of the first.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fM3mDX/1      This does not work for test

Comment: You copied delimiters mechanically. See https://regex101.com/r/fM3mDX/2.

Comment: And if my data looks like this: https://regex101.com/r/IUfqv4/1 actually it looks like this (JSON) thank you so far

Comment: \"test\"\:\s+.*    I did this